# AdActivity declared in AndroidManifest.xml with ConfigChanges for Admob

Tags: android, admob

I am working on an Android app and trying to implement Admob advertisement sdk. I have done everything that have been mentioned in the documentation but I am getting following error in red color in the black window which should have displayed advertisement.

> You must have AdActivity declared in AndroidManifest.xml with ConfigChanges

I have added following line in AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<activity
        android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation" />
```

I have tried but still I am not able to resolve this error. I am trying to run the application in my Xperia phone which has Android 4.0.4.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to put this in your manifest:

```
<activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
    android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"/>
```

AdViews handle a lot of configuration changes themselves. The official documentation can be found [here](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/).

According to [unify](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20233146/3037143), Admob is now integrated into Google Play Services. A migration reference can be found [here](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/play-migration).

Comment: but if I do this my app will only worn in android 3.2 onwards. I want my app to work in android 2.2 onwards

Comment: According to the documentation, it will run on Android 1.5 and later (`minSdkVersion`), but must be compiled against Android 3.2 or later (`targetSdkversion`).

Comment: Please don't forget to accept the answer if your problem is solved, or post back if you're still having problems.

Answer (score 2):

Updating the answer, the package has changed to:

```
<activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"      
android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"/>
```

Complete migration reference: https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/play-migration

Answer (score 1):

If you have still not solved this problem yet, I believe it is because you have to add some permissions for admob serves to serve ads to you

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```

Add these beneath the closing `</Activity>` tag

Hope this still helps